# Get the start of the previous instruction from an address

Tags: assembly, x86

We're in a buffer, looking at x86 opcodes. | marks the current pointer.

```
68 0F 00 6A 90 | 00
```

Finding the start of the next instruction is easy, since the size of the current is determinable. But how would you guess somewhat accurately the start of the previous?

`68 0F 00 6A 90` - 5 bytes total, ends at |

`0F 00 6A 90` - 4 bytes total, ends at |

`00 6A 90` - 3 bytes total, ends at |

`6A 90` - 2 bytes total, ends at |

`90` - 1 byte total, ends at |

Obviously this isn't a practical example, but it shows the issue. This is more a curiosity than a problem, but how do modern disassemblers accurately guess? Do they store points with call/jump references and find the nearest address to the nearest label that ends at the current instruction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with a variable length instruction set like this you cannot accurately linearly disassemble.  you have to start at an entry point and follow all the code paths you can, of course it is pretty easy to trip up a disassembler if that is all it does (force a condition then use a conditional branch, which will only take one path, and leave data in the unused path that trips up the following instruction decoding).  It is worse though if you just try to do it linearly from the entry point and not examine the data (for example when the compiler places poll data after an unconditional branch or return that your disassembler sees as instruction data).

You cant really accurately go backwards, unless you follow the code path with a branch that gets you there or somewhere in front of it that executes to it.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking something like this. Do you know how programs like olly can go to a random spot in memory and do it pretty well work? Or does it just work out eventually?

Comment: No I dont, I suspect but have not checked that some file formats leave information, like how does gnu objdump do such a good job?  Compiler generated code is going to be pretty clean and easy to disassemble, would need to try to trip up the tools to see how well they really do.  Although a jump table or function pointers may also trip them up if a raw binary is used and not a format with a lot of debug information.  Compiling for debug should be adding info to help out with this kind of thing, could do some experiments with that too...

Comment: If you think it through, there really is no other way, the processor obviously can find its way because it is executing every instruction completely.  A disassembler could try that but, it still may not work as some paths are user input dependent.  So without help from the file format, and not being able to execute the code through every code path, how else is it possible?  The best you can do is decode enough to know the length of each instruction, and follow all possible branches assuming each path of the conditionals is taken.